# How can I get a Localization object to query a different Publication

Tags: web8, dxa, c#, dxa-1.7

I'm new to DXA and faced an unknown while fetching DCP (or to say EntityModel) from other Publication. I've a pre populated Localization object which points to current Publication/site context. How can I get a Localization object for a different Publication?

My requirement is to fetch `EntityModels` from a different Publication then current!

I know, we get can `EntityModel` for current Publication like this:

```
DefaultContentProvider contentProvider = new DefaultContentProvider();
EventDetail eventDataModel = null;
try
{
    var eventData = contentProvider.GetEntityModel(new TcmUri(compId).ItemId + "-" + EventDetailCTID, _localization);
    eventDataModel = eventData as EventDetail;
}
catch (Exception e)
{
    // Error
}
```

How can we get a `_localization` object for some other Publication?

Use Case: Every locale specific dynamic components are published from each publications. There is a webpage where we want to display all these dynamic components (from all geos), on a single page.

Update: I found a way of getting the localization object using Resolver: 
ILocalizationResolver localizationResolver = new CdApiLocalizationResolver();
_localization = localizationResolver.ResolveLocalization(new Uri());

I tried localizationResolver.GetLocalization(), but this doesnt seems to build the object.

Comment: DXA isn't designed to work like you are trying to use it, the Localizations/Publications are there to separate sites completely. So I'm really wondering about the actual use case you have to fetch an Entity from a different Publication, perhaps if we know more about the use case we can think of a different solution (maybe BluePrinting can help etc.). so I suggest you **edit** your question and supply some more details.

Comment: BTW: you should not instantiate  Providers/Resolvers yourself, but use `SiteConfiguration.ContentProvider` and `SiteConfiguration.LocalizationResolver` to get instances of configured types (dependency injection).

Comment: Added the use case @BartKoopman. Sure will use SIteConfiguration

Answer (score 2):

Although your use case is still not really clear (and thus it is not clear if your **really** have to use cross-Localization logic), there is a way to ensure that a `Localization` object retrieved from `ILocalizationResolver.GetLocalization` is initialized:

```
Localization loc = SiteConfiguration.LocalizationResolver.GetLocalization(id);
loc.EnsureInitialized();
```

Comment: Rick - I just updated my use case. Thx for providing this method call.

Comment: What id are we expecting here? A full tcmid, e.g. tcm:0-303-1 or just the publication number, e.g. 303 or something else as it doesn't seem to work for me. I can get the localization using `ResolveLocalization(domain)` but in my current situation I don't have the domain, only the piblication Id of 303.

Comment: The ID of a DXA Localization is indeed just a number; the middle part of the Publication TCM URI.